# leftCalloutAccessoryView is set but now showing

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am setting up additional information to be displayed when a map pin is clicked.

In this annotation I am passing a button with an image into the rightCalloutAccessoryView but while it seems to reserve the space, it doesn't show the image.

I should also note that this is a copy from an app that DOES work and the images have been replaced with a different color scheme however I don't think the size of this image has changed but if the accessory view is sensitive to image size then that might be an issue.

Here is hoping this is just a nuance of the RightCalloutAccessoryView that I am missing.

```
  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
let reuseId = "mapViewPin"

var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    anView!.annotation = annotation

let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "goArrow"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
return anView
}
```

---

Here we have an example of the missing arrow image.

[image: What we see when I click on the pin]

---

And here we have what you would expect to see, a grey arrow.

[image: Image name, the image you would expect to see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.

The problem was that the system puts a tint on the image by default so I needed to override the tint to get the correct color.

The new code looks like this.

```
let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "goArrow")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button

return anView
```

The key here is using "imageWithRenderingMode" and to set as "AlwaysOriginal" which removes the default tint which for this image made it completely white.